# Add JavaScript to NewForm for SPList in SharePoint

Tags: c#, javascript, sharepoint

I have a SPList in SharePoint that I want to edit the NewForm.aspx for. I want to add a few JavaScripts as WebParts to the form programmatically.

How do I do that?

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Well, I have my SPContentType and tried to use the "NewFormUrl" but I cannot find the newform.aspx on my server. I simply don't know where to look.

Comment: @JamesMontagne: Seems like a fair question to me, the guy clearly is inexperienced.

Answer (score 2):

Open the list in SharePoint designer in the "lists and libraries" section. In the list designer view you will see a list of forms associated with the list, there will generally be a  "NewForm.aspx" form listed. Right click this and then select "Edit File in Advanced Mode" to expose the ASP .Net / HTML markup used for the form.

Now, add your custom  block within the page markup. I'd generally recommend that you find the asp:content element with id 'PlaceHolderMain'. Add your script as the first element immediately after the content placeholder element opens like:

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">
<script type='text/javascript' language='javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(e) { alert('my custom script has loaded'); });
</script>
..
.. Existing markup
..
</asp:Content>
```

My example above assumes you have jQuery present in your masterpage to display the message after the form has fully loaded.

Comment: @Servy: Not always necessary, the example I provided will only execute once the entire page / DOM has loaded anyway so there's no benefit to having the block in the head. Original poster also did not specify any standards compliance.

Comment: I didn't say it *needed* to go in head, merely that it should.  The fact that most browsers today allow you to do things that you shouldn't doesn't mean you should encourage such behavior.

Comment: I copied the code from the newform and pasted it in a aspx-file in vs2010. The code that sets the new form is contentType.NewFormUrl = @"C:\Hannes\Calendarwork\HannesCalendar\NewFormjs.aspx"; But I get the "Server Error in '/' Application. Runtime Error" when I activate the feature.

Comment: @carruw: The forms don't exist in physical .aspx files, they are stored in the site collection content database. Make sure that you make your changes and commit them back using the SharePoint designer tool. :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to (or can't) use SharePoint Designer you can put

?ToolpaneView=2

on the end of the URL to open the View/Edit/new form in design mode in the browser.

http://blog.pentalogic.net/2010/07/how-to-edit-list-forms-sharepoint-2010/

Comment: Been working with SharePoint for a long time.  This is the first time I have seen this tip.  Thank you.

Comment: Can you explain, please, how could it add scripts on `newform.aspx` page?

Comment: @AlexZhukovskiy - you open the page in edit mode (as shown here) then add a Centent Editor Web Part (CEWP) to the page that will hold your script.

Comment: Oh, I've got it. I think that it's not "programmicaly". I found a real automated solution: export newform.aspx, modify it as you want, then use it in list shema and deploy it.

Comment: @AlexZhukovskiy How do you export newform.aspx?

Comment: @Alex sorry, I actually don't recall. I changed my work, removed everything related to SharePoint from my CV, deleted all SP projects and sweared to never touch it again. So now I'm happy with aspnetcore and Rust projects, so I wish for you.